# Redoing the standard classes

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

As evidenced by the Typeclassopedia, the current stack of classes imported from category theory is a bit of a tangled accident of history, rather than a beautiful coherent whole.

In particular, this makes it rather difficult to follow what's happening.

What *should* this stuff look like, if petty concerns like backwards compatibility, code duplication or tractably short type signatures were not an issue?

Comment: The classes weren't imported from category theory.

Comment: @DonStewart: Perhaps I was unclear. I'm not claiming that the idea of a type-class comes from category theory. I'm referring to the Haskell type-classes that are based on category theory - `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` and so forth.

Comment: OK. I've revised my answer to distinguish attempts to categorize the numeric classes; and the category-theoretic classes.

Comment: @closers: the design of type-class hierarchies is quite difficult, and while I could wish for more depth in the answers, I still find the question and the accepted answer quite useful.  Please reconsider your close votes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For some subsets of the standard classes there have been attempts to give revised hierarchies.

**Numeric Typeclasses**

- [The Numeric Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude).  An experimental alternative hierarchy of numeric type classes

In particular, it provides a much richer set of mathematical abstractions.

Besides this, there are many other alternate designs:

- [Yet Another Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yap) - a notable alternate prelude from Ross Paterson:

[image]

- [prelude-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-extras) - higher order prelude functions
- [classy-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ClassyPrelude) - a prelude with more classes

**Categoric Typeclasses**

There's been less work on [the category-inspired classes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory), such as Functor, Monad, Monoid, Applicative and of course, Category.

The most important work is the

- [category-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras) package, which provides a very rich library indeed, including the famous zygohistoprepromorphism.

[image]

Comment: +1 for lots and lots of interesting references.

Comment: Do any of the above address the Monad/Functor inversion?

Comment: I looked at that graph, and my brain exploded. o_O But then, it's category theory, right? I did _ask_ for it... ;-)

Comment: The second graph is dependencies of packages, which is bit different. [The original graph in Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Image:Typeclassopedia-diagram.png) _does_ have a Functor -> Applicative -> Monad arrow.

Comment: Yeah, it broadly maps to the nesting of classes, but is not precise.

Comment: Daniel Pratt: the 'Monad/Functor inversion'???

Comment: Well, "inversion" was not the best choice of term. I assumed it would be understood what situation I was referring to. I am speaking of the fact that in the current standard Prelude, Functor and Applicative are not superclasses of Monad, as indicated by Typeclassopedia. Whereas there are instance declarations for both Functor and Applicative that are based on Monad, it seemed to me there was a bit of an "inversion" in the current Prelude.

Comment: But there are also superclasses of, say, Applicative -- and other opposing superclasses of Monad -- see e.g. the picture http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-1.3.1.2 -- Witness the inversion in making instance of Apply and Bind http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroupoids/1.3.1.2/doc/html/src/Data-Functor-Bind.html . The [pointed package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pointed/2.1.0.1/doc/html/src/Data-Pointed.html) uses whatever comes to mind ; there doesn't seem to be any failure of principle in this.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the "categorical" classes, there is also [The Other Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).
The class hierarchy outlined there has been implemented in [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege/).

Comment: Damned daily voting cap. :-P Regardless, this is possibly the best thing I've read all day. Not only does The Other Prelude explain the main classes of interest in a simple and succinct way, but until today I had never heard of Frege. :-D

Comment: No worries, @MathematicalOrchid, because of the vote ... Don put more effort in his answer and he was first. And added nice graphics.

Comment: Frege sounds extremely exciting. How in the name of goodness do you actually pronounce it though?! o_O

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - I should write a FAQ :) Seriously, go to Google Translator, select translate from German, and type Frege in the box, then a small symbol will appear in the lower right corner of the box, and if you click that, a german women's voice will read it to you.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't matter. I know many peple that pronounce "Turing" like "touring", I guess if one is as famous as these great men one will have to live with that.

Comment: @Ingo Oh dear, you definitely did _not_ pick a name that would be easy to pronounce by native-English-speaking folks such as myself :) (not implying that should have been your goal).

Comment: @DanielPratt - ha, this is the revenge! Think of all the millions, if not billions of non-english speakers that need to learn the th!

Comment: @Ingo We definitely had it coming :)

Comment: Google translate seems to think that "freega" is a better pronunciation, but hey, whatever. I just want to see if it _works_. ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid the project page I linked should give you all information and resources you need to try it out.

Comment: It's pronounced like "fray-guh", emphasis on the first syllable.